# Why does my created Exception not work in Java?

Tags: java, exception, user-input

I created an Exception that doesn't work : Here I create a product object with a productName string variable as parameter. I put the product in a list named productAvailable. I ask the user which product they want to update and tell them to write the name of the product. I then use a method(searchProduct) to search wether there is a product of that name. This program use a iterator to search wether there is a product with the productName and is supposed to throw an Exception if not. A boolean is used to find out wethere the product is there or not. Yet it works all the time.
Even If I write the right input it throws an exception which is caught. Here "Apple" should be equal to the product name in the list and not throw an exception. I do not understand why it does that. Please help. Thanks in advance.

I wanted the Exception to work only when I put the wrong Input.

```
public static void searchProduct(String name) throws InvalidInputException{
        Iterator<Product> itr = productAvailable.iterator();
        boolean productIsNotThere = true;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.next().getProductName().equals(name)) {
                productIsNotThere = false;
            }
        }
        if(productIsNotThere) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("The product you are looking for is no longer in stock or this is not the right product name");
        }
    }

//if the product is there it should send a message, if not throw an exception with a message)
```

```
        Product apple = new Product("111111", "Apple", 1, 100); 
        //contructor : Product( productID, ProductName, price, quantity)

        Collections.addAll(Inventory_Management.getProductAvailable(), apple, kiwi, banana);
```

````
 System.out.println("Give me the product name of the product you want to update");
               
                String name = "Apple";

                try {
                    Inventory_Management.searchProduct(name);
                } catch(InvalidInputException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }```
````

Comment: The problem is not the exception itself, but on the way you're looking for your product inside the productInventory. Your research looks pretty strange. What kind of collection is productInventory? Why not using a Map<String, Product> instead and simply looking for the key (which is faster and way easier)?

Comment: Debugging is a useful skill. If you want to become a professional software developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, it will be a necessary skill. Run this program in a debugger. Set a breakpoint at Iterator<Product> itr = productAvailable.iterator(); then run the program one-step-at-a-time monitoring the values of variables.

Comment: Looks like we need to see more code to figure out what is wrong. Consider providing a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hello @Matteo Thanks for answering. I used a set because I ddidn't want duplicate product to be update inside the collection. I didn't use a map beacause I wasn't familliar with it but I might try if I can't find out how to do it

Comment: @Old Dog Programmer I tried with debbuging like you asked. The value I put in is "Apple" and it becomes : "". I do not know what that means. How I do I put more of what I coded ? Should I answer my own question or should I edit ?

Comment: You should edit your question to include more code. We should be able to copy your code, paste it into our IDE, and then run it.

Comment: The `name` (or whatever it is called) field in the `apple` instance of your `Product` is an empty String? That suggests a fault in the constructor, so we should see the code for the constructors. I think we should also see the code for `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Product` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... Even If I write the right input it throws an exception which is caught. Here "Apple" should be equal to the product name in the list and not throw an exception. ..."*

Your code seems to work correctly.
Here is an adaptation.

```java
static List<Product> productAvailable = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new Product("Apple"));
}};

public static void searchProduct(String name) throws InvalidInputException{
    Iterator<Product> itr = productAvailable.iterator();
    boolean productIsNotThere = true;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (itr.next().getProductName().equals(name)) {
            productIsNotThere = false;
        }
    }
    if(productIsNotThere) {
        throw new InvalidInputException("The product you are looking for is no longer in stock or this is not the right product name");
    }
}

static class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
    InvalidInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

static class Product {
    String productName;

    public Product(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
}
```

If I search for *"abc"*, the exception is thrown, and if I search for *"Apple"* no exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" Example$InvalidInputException: The product you are looking for is no longer in stock or this is not the right product name
    at Example.searchProduct ...
    at Example.main ...
```

If the *[Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html)* is not functioning as intended, I suggest reviewing the *Java* documentation.
*[Lesson: Exceptions (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)*.

And, as a recommendation, you can simplify your current *searchProduct* code with a *[Stream#noneMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))* call.

```java
public static void searchProduct(String name) throws InvalidInputException{
    if (productAvailable.stream().noneMatch(x -> x.getProductName().equals(name)))
        throw new InvalidInputException("The product you are looking for is no longer in stock or this is not the right product name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code I see looks ok.  Calling

```
            throw new InvalidInputException("...");
```

will definitely cause the exception, so that code must not be called.
A simple test would be to change the if statements logic to:

```
        if(productIsNotThere || true) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("The product you are looking for is no longer in stock or this is not the right product name");
        }
```

My guess is that something else in the logic is incorrect `productIsNotThere == false`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Kenny, It looks to me as if the suggested code change was not intended to fix your code, but to solicit more information.  When I first read the question, I thought the exception was *not* being thrown when it should be. The suggested change in this answer is intended to force the exception to be thrown.